# Idenfying bigrams using Gensim Phraser that contain the word "not," for sentiment analysis

Tags: nlp, gensim, sentiment-analysis, phrase

I am working on a sentiment analysis project where I am analyzing a corpus of documents, and I am specifically *not* removing the word "not" as a stopword, so that I can use it to determine if a text agrees or disagrees with something. For instance, there is a difference between "not effective" and "effective" when discussing the COVID vaccine.

However, my phraser is not identifying any bigrams with the word "not." I presume this is because that token exists in such large numbers (particularly because I expanded contractions, so "isn't" -> "is not"), that the scoring function simply scores all bigrams with "not" too low. This would be because the standard phrase scoring function is:

[image: bigram scoring function]

(where `min_count` is a hyper parameter)

So, since "not" exists many thousands of times in the database, `worda_count` will be **very** large, leading to a large denominator and dropping the score considerably.

Is there a way to get around this, so "not" bigrams are scored effectively?

I can think of a few options off the top of my head:

1. Write my own scoring function that effectively has two scoring formula: the standard scoring formula, and a different scoring formula if the first word is "not".
2. I could include "not" in a list of `connector_words`, but `gensim.models.phrases.Phraser` *specifically* indicates that these connector words cannot be at the beginning or end of a phrase.

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, the `Phrases` functionality in Gensim is pretty crude: it only combines words based on a meaning-oblivious statistical analysis. It's more likely to be helpful in promoting certain noun-phrases (`'new_york'`) or idioms  than generic syntactical reversals-of-meaning (as with an added `'not'`). So whether you'll want to use it at all, I'm not sure.

You could try the most simpleminded thing possible: preprocess to *always* attach `'not'` to the following word. Maybe it'll help!

You could also try some expensive grammar-aware preprocessing - the sort that labels words with parts-of-speech, & further identifies which other words/word-ranges a particular `'not'` modifies. That might allow you to condiionally connect the `'not'` to later words – maybe even non-contiguous words – & perhaps that will provide a lift to downstream sentiment-analysis.